# Upload static PDF on meteor deploy

Tags: pdf, meteor, iron-router

I have a PDF in my public folder, and when I run meteor locally I can link to it with iron router. However, when I deploy my site to meteor.com, I get a server error when trying to access the pdf. The rest of my routes are working fine, it just seems like the PDF does not get uploaded to the server. Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you do a "meteor logs yourappname.meteor.com" and have a look at the logs (or post them)? They might tell you whats going wrong, or at least point you in the right direction. Also have a look at the path you use for your uploads folder, and have a look at this post:

Comment: The log says:
WARNING Error: ENOENT, no such file
or directory '//public/filename.pdf'
It works well locally, but when I deploy it iron router cannot find the file

Comment: Can you link the post you're referencing also? thanks!

Comment: Sorry, forgot to link to the post and don't have the link right now but based on the message you are getting, can you post the exact code and path you are using to access the file?